# I am using a Hindi udpipe model and creating a wordcloud in Shiny apl with some text. The wordcloud is not showing me the words.

Tags: shiny

I am using a Hindi udpipe model and creating a wordcloud in Shiny apl with some text. The wordcloud is not showing me the words. It is just showing square like characters in mac.

Comment: Sounds like a character encoding (utf8?, ...) related problem.

Comment: Please share the minimal code and sample data that you have tried.

Comment: hindi_model = udpipe_load_model("./hindi-ud-2.0-170801.udpipe")  x <- udpipe_annotate(hindi_model, x = text)
  x <- as.data.frame(x) library(wordcloud)
wordcloud(words = top_nouns$key, 
          freq = top_nouns$freq, 
          min.freq = 2, 
          max.words = 100,
          random.order = FALSE, 
          colors = brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"))

Comment: This is the code i used.